# How to block api access from certain country or region?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, server

i am searching for best solution to restrict user access to my API . i want restrict users to get access to my API .

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things, which you can do is.

1. Write your own code, block the user based on certain factors for the country.
   Example - Use IP location,location,timezone,navigator.language,Accept-Language etc.
   From all this factors one can filter out the request coming from the country. It might
   not be efficient in some cases.
2. Use cdn providers like cloudflare, in which you can block the access from several
   countries and everything handled by them.

Comment: 2nd solution seems paid , is there any free solution  ?

Comment: No,it's not paid.Just need to use cloudflare as your cdn.And it will send user's country as header.

Go through the documentation.https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation-do-#12345680